# why elasticsearch cluster in kubernetes start so slow

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, startup

I am start elasticsearch cluster(v6.4.3) pod in kubernetes cluster(v1.15.2),but the each pod start spent more than 20min. The image file already pull to local,what should I do to make it start faster?

[image]

everytime I restart the cluster takes more than 1 hour.Is it possible to make it start it less than 1min?This is my yaml of elasticsearch:

```
{
  "kind": "StatefulSet",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "es-cluster",
    "namespace": "logging",
    "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/logging/statefulsets/es-cluster",
    "uid": "06afbdc1-3ada-401e-8e62-74c6ce4aba97",
    "resourceVersion": "18109360",
    "generation": 44,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-02-28T06:28:48Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "elasticsearch"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{\"apiVersion\":\"apps/v1\",\"kind\":\"StatefulSet\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"name\":\"es-cluster\",\"namespace\":\"logging\"},\"spec\":{\"replicas\":1,\"selector\":{\"matchLabels\":{\"app\":\"elasticsearch\"}},\"serviceName\":\"elasticsearch\",\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"elasticsearch\"}},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"env\":[{\"name\":\"cluster.name\",\"value\":\"k8s-logs\"},{\"name\":\"node.name\",\"valueFrom\":{\"fieldRef\":{\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.name\"}}},{\"name\":\"discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts\",\"value\":\"es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch\"},{\"name\":\"discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes\",\"value\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"ES_JAVA_OPTS\",\"value\":\"-Xms512m -Xmx512m\"}],\"image\":\"registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/elasticsearch-oss:6.4.3\",\"name\":\"elasticsearch\",\"ports\":[{\"containerPort\":9200,\"name\":\"rest\",\"protocol\":\"TCP\"},{\"containerPort\":9300,\"name\":\"inter-node\",\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}],\"resources\":{\"limits\":{\"cpu\":\"1000m\"},\"requests\":{\"cpu\":\"100m\"}},\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/usr/share/elasticsearch/data\",\"name\":\"data\"}]}],\"imagePullSecrets\":[{\"name\":\"regcred\"}],\"initContainers\":[{\"command\":[\"sh\",\"-c\",\"chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data\"],\"image\":\"docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1\",\"name\":\"fix-permissions\",\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true},\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/usr/share/elasticsearch/data\",\"name\":\"data\"}]},{\"command\":[\"sysctl\",\"-w\",\"vm.max_map_count=262144\"],\"image\":\"docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1\",\"name\":\"increase-vm-max-map\",\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true}},{\"command\":[\"sh\",\"-c\",\"ulimit -n 65536\"],\"image\":\"docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1\",\"name\":\"increase-fd-ulimit\",\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true}}]}},\"volumeClaimTemplates\":[{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"app\":\"elasticsearch\"},\"name\":\"data\"},\"spec\":{\"accessModes\":[\"ReadWriteOnce\"],\"resources\":{\"requests\":{\"storage\":\"5Gi\"}},\"storageClassName\":\"es-data-db\"}}]}}\n"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 3,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "elasticsearch"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "elasticsearch"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "initContainers": [
          {
            "name": "fix-permissions",
            "image": "docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1",
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "data",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": true
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "increase-vm-max-map",
            "image": "docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1",
            "command": [
              "sysctl",
              "-w",
              "vm.max_map_count=262144"
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": true
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "increase-fd-ulimit",
            "image": "docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1",
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "ulimit -n 65536"
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "elasticsearch",
            "image": "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/elasticsearch:6.4.3",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "rest",
                "containerPort": 9200,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "inter-node",
                "containerPort": 9300,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "cluster.name",
                "value": "k8s-logs"
              },
              {
                "name": "node.name",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "fieldRef": {
                    "apiVersion": "v1",
                    "fieldPath": "metadata.name"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts",
                "value": "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
              },
              {
                "name": "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes",
                "value": "2"
              },
              {
                "name": "ES_JAVA_OPTS",
                "value": "-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "100m"
              }
            },
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "data",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "nodeSelector": {
          "app-type": "assistant-app"
        },
        "securityContext": {},
        "imagePullSecrets": [
          {
            "name": "regcred"
          }
        ],
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "volumeClaimTemplates": [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "name": "data",
          "creationTimestamp": null,
          "labels": {
            "app": "elasticsearch"
          }
        },
        "spec": {
          "accessModes": [
            "ReadWriteOnce"
          ],
          "resources": {
            "requests": {
              "storage": "5Gi"
            }
          },
          "storageClassName": "es-data-db",
          "volumeMode": "Filesystem"
        },
        "status": {
          "phase": "Pending"
        }
      }
    ],
    "serviceName": "elasticsearch",
    "podManagementPolicy": "OrderedReady",
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "partition": 0
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 44,
    "replicas": 2,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "currentReplicas": 2,
    "updatedReplicas": 2,
    "currentRevision": "es-cluster-6b6647d94",
    "updateRevision": "es-cluster-6b6647d94",
    "collisionCount": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: is it going in CrashLoopBackOff ?

Comment: See the pod's logs. You might have some weird retries policies with timeouts. In my experience this happened when another service was not responding but in your case maybe it waits after a file or something similar. Share also the relevant logs after investigating them.

Comment: Make sure the volume mount works fine without delay. Check InitContainer completion time . InitContainer startup is sequential , so that can addup to startup time. Logging in InitContainer will help. Finally you can debug the elastic-search itself via its logs.

Comment: yes, add `kubectl logs <pod_name>` and `kubectl get events`, `kubectl describe <pod_name>` so we can help you further.

Comment: I found maybe the data cause it start so slow,I deleted the data folder and the pods start very quickly.Mybe the chown command in the initial container cause the problem.

Comment: @Dolphin write your solution as an Answer so you can help others in the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data is not important,I delete the cluster data folder and restart.It is fast.Read the elasticsearch file and remove the init container chown command should fix this.chown when first time run your clusterif needed directory permission.Just remove:

```
         {
            "name": "fix-permissions",
            "image": "docker.io/library/busybox:1.31.1",
            "command": [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "data",
                "mountPath": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
            "securityContext": {
              "privileged": true
            }
          }
```